Staking native token on Cardano
Can you please help me.
Smart contracts (or some other way) for staking are possible on Cardano?
Is this possible?
User should be able to stake own (native) token on platform
Reward formula: Stake amount X APR/100 X Period Days/365
Unstake fee - X ADA, Claim fee - Y ADA
The rewards should be available for Claim or Restake after the end of the period.
And if possible, are there any links to similar projects?
Thanks!

Staking ADA serves a purpose. It secures the Cardano network and people get rewarded in ADA for securing the network.
Native tokens rely on the security of the Cardano network, so why would native tokens get any staking rewards?

The question is very strange.
In general, the answer is to interest users in using your token.
I'm asking about an analogue of staking tokens on Ethereum. It exists and is widely used.
If continue your reasoning, then why are there tokens at all in Cardano, after all, there is ADA. Why Cardano, after all, there is Bitcoin :)

Tokens have utility beyond staking. Cardano offers a bunch of features that Bitcoin does not and cannot offer.
We will see if the tokens on ETH that offer staking have any economic utility. I suspect that long term they will not.
